# Losing Spark Executors with many tasks outstanding

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

Whether I use dynamic allocation or explicitly specify executors (16) and executor cores (8), I have been losing executors even though the tasks outstanding are well beyond the current number of executors.

For example, I have a job (Spark SQL) running with over 27,000 tasks and 14,000 of them were complete, but executors "decayed" from 128 down to as few as 16 with thousands of tasks still outstanding. The log doesn't note any errors/exceptions precipitating these lost executors.

It is a Cloudera CDH 5.10 cluster running on AWS EC2 instances with 136 CPU cores and Spark 2.1.0 (from Cloudera).

```
17/05/23 18:54:17 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 91 executor(s).
17/05/23 18:54:17 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 91 executors.
```

It's a slow decay where every minute or so more executors are removed.

Some potentially relevant configuration options:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors = 136
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors = 1
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors = 1
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 8
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores = 1
yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores = 1
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores = 8
```

Why are the executors decaying away and how can I prevent it?

Comment: What kind of job is this? Does it cause a lot of shuffle? For example in a map-reduce like job, if there are only 16 keys to reduce too, Then it will only use 16 executors.

Comment: Also please reference https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation, Did you enabled dynamic resource allocation?

Comment: @xuanyue It's a SELECT statement that joins multiple (parquet-backed) tables together, grabbing several columns from one table and a few from the other tables as well. Some of the data is NOT replicated much, so one theory I had was that the executors that didn't have the relevant data were being dropped. That seems questionable since there are regularly SO many tasks outstanding, but possible I guess.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: me too , same issue when initializing a graph with graphx, did you have any solution?